# IBM MobileFirst 7.0 - Adapter Invocation

Tags: javascript, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

Can we send multiple records at a time to Adapter and also can we send object to Adapter.
here is the sample Adapter code:

```
var addStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into MSS (ENO,ENAME,ESALARY) values (?, ?, ?)");
function addSQLAdapterDemo(param0,param1,param2) {
return WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({
    preparedStatement : addStatement,
    parameters : [param0,param1,param2]
});
```

}

Main.js in Client side javascript:

```
$('button#InsertData').on('click', function () {
  var invocationData = {
  adapter : 'SQLAdapterDemo', 
  procedure : 'addSQLAdapterDemo', 
  parameters : [5,'Raj',25000][6,'karan',25000],
  compressResponse: true
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData);
```

In the Above code I pass three params can we send data like this. And Aslo Can We send object to Adapter.  the object is having those three params.

Comment: Are you asking because your code is not working, or it is working but you are asking to check if it is okay to do so? What is the problem?

Comment: @Idan Adar It is not working for me. And also I want conformation that can we send object to Adapters.

Comment: 1) How is it failing? What error are you getting? 2) Define "objects"

Comment: In Console I got Error Like : response [/Offline/apps/services/api/JSONStoreAPI/common/query] success: /*-secure-
{"errors":["Runtime: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.61.75.\nPerformed query:\ninsert into MSS (ENO,ENAME,ESALARY) values (?, ?, ?)"],"isSuccessful":false,"warnings":[],"info":[]}*/                                          Procedure invocation error. Runtime: DB2 SQL Error: SQLCODE=-313, SQLSTATE=07004, SQLERRMC=null, DRIVER=3.61.75.
Performed query:
insert into MSS (ENO,ENAME,ESALARY) values (?, ?, ?)

Comment: I got Object from JSONstore like  this sample Example [
 {
  "_id": 1,
  "json": {}
 },
 {
  "_id": 2,
  "json": {
   "name": "vinod",
   "age": 23
  }
 },
 {
  "_id": 3,
  "json": {
   "age": 23,
   "name": "chevy"
  }
 },
 {
  "_id": 4,
  "json": {
   "age": 23,
   "name": "yoel"
  }
 },
 {
  "_id": 5,
  "json": {
   "age": 23,
   "name": "vinod"
  }
 }
]

Comment: Actully I'm working on offline data sync in mobilefirst. When ever there is no internet connection data will be stored in JSONStores in the form Objects once user got the internet connection the whole data must revert back to adapters at that time for that  I want to enter complete records those records are jsonObjects in clear.

Comment: @VinodKumarMarupu you can implement adapter in such a way that it will take JSON Array which contains your records in form of json object and you invokeSQLStatement by iterating over json array.

Comment: @Mo.Ashfaq Great. Do you have any sample code for this.

Comment: 'parameters : [5,'Raj',25000][6,'karan',25000],' this line is not correct javascript. You can't put 2 arrays next to each other like that. Try @Mo.Ashfaq 's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try this code :

```
/*---------------------------------
Adapter Code
---------------------------------*/
var addStatement = WL.Server.createSQLStatement("insert into MSS (ENO,ENAME,ESALARY) values (?, ?, ?)");
function addSQLAdapterDemo(allRecords) {

var oneRecord;
for ( var count = 0; count < allRecords.length; count++ ){

    oneRecord = allRecords[count];
    WL.Server.invokeSQLStatement({preparedStatement : addStatement,parameters : [oneRecord.id,oneRecord.name,oneRecord.salary]});

}

/*---------------------------------
Client Code
---------------------------------*/
$('button#InsertData').on('click', function () {

/*Preparing JSON Array*/
    var allRecordJson = [];
    allRecordJson.push({"id":"5", "name" : "Raj", "salary" : "25000"});
    allRecordJson.push({"id":"6", "name" : "Karan", "salary" : "20000"});
/*JSON Array Builded*/

  var invocationData = {
  adapter : 'SQLAdapterDemo', 
  procedure : 'addSQLAdapterDemo', 
  parameters : [allRecordJson],
  compressResponse: true
};
WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData);
}
```